# How to get logged users user_id from the database and insert it to another table?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've been trying to get logged persons `user_id` which is in `user_login` table in my database and insert it to the another table.
What I know is, get the `user_id` from the `user_login` using query and assign that query to the SESSION variable and put that variable in another query where I want to insert it in the table but I'm unable to write a perfect code for it.The only thing I'm achieving is it taking the `user_id` as 1 in the new table.It would be a great help if you can review my code correct it.

```
    <?php 
    ob_start();
    include ('header.php');
    require('includes/connect.php');
    require('includes/product.php');

    $product = new Product;         
    if(isset ($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = $product -> fetch_data($id);    

        if(isset($_POST['add'])){
            if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
                $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM user_login ");
                $user_id=$query->execute();
                $_SESSION['user_id']['id']=$user_id;
                $query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO cart_items(product_id , user_id, Price) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                $query -> bindValue(1, $id);
                $query -> bindValue(2, $_SESSION['user_id']['id']);
                $query -> bindValue(3, $data['new_price']);
                $query ->execute();
                header('location:cart.php');
            }
            else{
                header('location:Login Page.php');
            }
        }
?>
```

This is where I have done the user validation while logging in (connect.php)

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "ecom";
try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ecom','root','');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    exit('Database error.');
}

 function login(){
     global $pdo;
     $username = $_POST['email'];
                $password = md5($_POST['password']);
                if(empty($username) or empty($password))
                {
                    $error = "Please fill all the fields";
                }
                else
                {
                    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE name = ? AND password = ? ");
                    $query->bindValue ( 1, $username);
                    $query->bindValue ( 2, $password);
                    $query->execute();
                    $num=$query->rowCount();

                if($num==1) {
                    $_SESSION['logged_in']= true;
                    //header('location :' .$_SESSION['redirectURL']);
                    header('location: index.php');
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    $error = "Please enter correct Username and Password";
                }
            }


}


?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: with $_SESSION tracking, a Insert, and maybe a Select query....

Comment: You should add the user id to your session variable when the user logs in. This doesn't make sense as you are retrieving all users and `execute()` returns a boolean.

Comment: @jeroen could you please let me know on how to do that. I've also added a code of the validation of the user while logging in.

Comment: MD5 is not meant for securing passwords. Instead it has been optimized for speed (to create quick checksums). Instead if it, you should be using the new [Password API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace your else part with this code

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE name = ? AND password = ? ");
$query->bindValue ( 1, $username);
$query->bindValue ( 2, $password);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$num=$query->rowCount();

if($num==1) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in']= true;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data[0]["user_id"];
    //header('location :' .$_SESSION['redirectURL']);
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
} else{
     $error = "Please enter correct Username and Password";
}
```

then you can get user id from session

Comment: okay now can we use this variable in another file.You can see the the query in my question right it's actually in another file.

Comment: ofc, you can use session variable in any file within your project

Comment: your query `SELECT user_id FROM user_login` will get all users because it does not contain where condition  and `$query->execute();` return boolean not the data so you will get always 1

Comment: Though I'm logged in with another account whose user_id is 2 , But still it is taking a 1 .Do you have any idea?

Comment: No I 've removed that query now my query is like below. 
  `if(isset($_POST['add'])){`
   `if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {`
    `$query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO cart_items(product_id , user_id, Price) VALUES (?,?,?)");`
    `$query -> bindValue(1, $id);`
    `$query -> bindValue(2, $_SESSION['user_id']);`
    `$query -> bindValue(3, $data['new_price']);`
    `$query ->execute();`
    `header('location:cart.php');`
   `}`
   `else{`
    `header('location:Login Page.php');`
   `}`
  `}`

Comment: add `print_r($data);die();` below $num=$query->rowCount();  check the output

Comment: will the query like this work?

`SELECT user_id FROM user_login Where user_id=_SESSION['user_id']`

Comment: This is what I got after clicking submit in login page.
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 2 [name] => anil [password] => ea3d0c5687cd241635ca2c91d71255ee ) )`

details are correct.

Comment: then you just have to set session variable  with `$_SESSION["user_id"] = $data[0]["user_id"]`, then you can use `$_SESSION["user_id"]` to get id anywhere

Comment: I used this one `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $data[0]['user_id']` and its working fine thanks bro.